# Ubuntu GUI is ugly after updating graphic drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, gui

I just installed Ubuntu 10.10 on my desktop computer and saw the nice looking scroll bars on the windows.

I then installed the NVIDIA drivers for my GTX 275 card and rebooted. Now however, the GUI interfaces look very old and unattractive. See the screen shot below; look at the scroll bars in particular.

Is there some sort of setting that I need to fix so the GUI goes back to the better look?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: “Unattractive” and “better look” are subjective. I don't see anything wrong with the scroll bars in your screen shot. You should also post a screenshot with the look you expect. Also for this question you may get better answers at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/). If you do post there, link the questions to each other so people can easily find both sets of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Themeing of controls and such can be tweaked under Preferences > Appearance. Click the Customize button under the Theme tab. I imagine the nvidia drivers wrote over whatever settings were in place previously.

Comment: But scroll bars aren't an option under customizations?

Comment: I can actually see the better looking scroll bars under the customization options, but not when the theme is applied.

Comment: Scrollbars fall under 'Controls', along with radio buttons, titlebars, etc. It should be the first tab displayed under 'Customize'.

Comment: That also didn't do anything :(

Answer (score 0):

There are sometimes two options for NVIDIA drivers, try deactivating the one you are currently using and activating the one that you are not.